# Change to AMP page based on screen size

Tags: amp-html

I'm looking for a super easy way to make my normal html page, change to my AMP page based on a smaller screen size. Can this be done via the header?

Answer (score 0):

I use following and it works perfectly. Doesn't change to AMP on tablets which is fine as my site is responsive.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "https://example.com/amp";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: AMP is all about serving pages faster (from Google cache). And this solution does exactly opposite.